# Vue js vee validate password confirmation with custom components

Tags: validation, vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

I use `vee-validate` in my project with custom components with no problems.

But now for a Password Confirmation input field, I'm not able to make it work properly.

I have custom components for the input fields, somethink like `<base-input-field>`.

If I add a `ref="password"` attribute in my custom component (`<base-input-field ref="password">`), it will not reference the `<input>` inside my custom component, but the `<div>` wrapper that encapsulates the `<input>` html component.

Code example:

```
            <!-- Password -->
            <div class="row">
              <base-text-field
                ref="password"
                name="password"
                type="password"
                :error="isVisible && errors.first('password')"
                v-validate="{
                  required: true,
                  min: 6,
                  max: 30,
                }"
                v-model.trim="password"
                required
              />
            </div>

            <!-- Confirm Password -->
            <div class="row">
              <base-text-field
                name="password_conf"
                type="password"
                :error="isVisible && errors.first('password_conf')"
                v-validate="{
                  required: true,
                  confirmed: 'password',
                }"
                :data-vv-as="password"
                v-model.trim="password_conf"
                required
              />
            </div>
```

Comment: The answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59369873/vee-validate-3-x-cross-field-validation#:~:text=According%20to%20vee%2Dvalidate%20docs,the%20rules%20of%20the%20other.) question will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know `vee-validate` but here is an idea from a similar problem I had with custom components not having access to `<input>` directly:

Get the reference to the input using JS:

`this.$refs.password.$el.querySelector("input")`

You could save it in a variable and pass it to your component I guess. Again, I don't know `vee-validate`. Hope it gives you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Can u check which events are supported on your custom component(May be @input/@change)?

If any of events are fired on change of your input there is an option **data-vv-validate-on** in v-validate where you can set on which event you want to check the validation. Read more [here](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/api/data-attrs.html)

```
<base-text-field
            ref="password"
            name="password"
            type="password"
            :error="isVisible && errors.first('password')"
            v-validate="{
              required: true,
              min: 6,
              max: 30,
            }"
            v-model.trim="password"
            data-vv-validate-on="change"
            required
          />
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the requirements in [this page](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/examples/custom-component.html) and you should be fine:

- emit `input` event when the value in your component changes
- have `name` and `value` defined in component via [$_veeValidate](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/concepts/components.html#component-constructor-options).  Or, use `data-vv-name` and `data-vv-value-path` (details [here](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/api/data-attrs.html)).

Since you didn't provide the code in `base-text-field` I can't really give you any further example of how it should work for you.