# vee-validate 3.x cross field validation

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js, vee-validate

I have component FromTo that takes 2 Timepickers components and cross validate one Timepicker component (**From**) to another (**To**). To timepicker has a **greater** vee-validate cross-field rule applied to it that looks like this:

```
   extend("greater", {
     params:["target"],
     validate(value, {target}){

     let regex = new RegExp("\d{2}:\d{2}", "g");

     console.log("from is "+target);   // prints @from instead of @from value
     console.log("value is "+value);

      return regex.test(value)
       &&  regex.test(target)
       &&  value > target; 

    },
     message: "To field must be greater that from field"
 });
```

Component body looks like this

```
<ValidationObserver>    
        <div class="flex mb-16 flex-wrap w-full">
            <div class="mr-1">
                <label class="font-bold block">From</label>
                <ValidationProvider name="from" rules="required|time" v-slot="{ errors }">
                    <VueTimepicker 
                        v-model="val.from"
                        close-on-complete
                        :input-class="['px-3', 'py-2', 'border', 'rounded', (errors.length ? 'border-red-400' : 'border-gray-400')]" 
                        />
                    <span class="text-sm w-40 block mt-1 text-red-400" v-if="errors.length"> {{ errors[0] }} </span>
                </ValidationProvider>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="font-bold block">To</label>
                <ValidationProvider name="to" rules="required|time|greater:@from" v-slot="{ errors }">
                    <VueTimepicker 
                        v-model="val.to" 
                        close-on-complete
                        :input-class="['px-3', 'py-2', 'border', 'rounded', (errors.length ? 'border-red-400' : 'border-gray-400')]"
                    />
                    <span class="text-sm w-40 block mt-1 text-red-400" v-if="errors.length"> {{ errors[0] }} </span>
                </ValidationProvider>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ValidationObserver>
```

I can see my rule being targeted but console logs **@from** instead of @from value. According to vee-validate docs in order for cross-field validation rule to work following criteria must be met:

> Wrap the fields within the same ValidationObserver component.
>   The target field must have a name or vid prop.
>   Properly reference the target field name or vid value in the rules of the other.

I have also properly referenced from field

> To reference another field's value, add a @ at the beginning of a param to signal to vee-validate that it should substitute the param with the target field value. So instead of getting a static "confirm" string, you will get the field's value instead.

I know I could possibly target static value like this:

```
rules=`required|time|greater:${this.from}`
```

But I would really want to target field values using @ sign. I 've simplified this example as I could and all the inner v-model bindings are correct. (from, to and entire component). I've been breaking my head around this for quite some time and red documentation carefully and would really appreciate any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your validation function to look like this:

```
extend("greater", {
  params: ["target"],
  validate(value, { target }) {
    let regex = new RegExp(/^\d{2}:\d{2}$/);

    return regex.test(value) && regex.test(target) && value > target;
  },
  message: "To field must be greater that from field"
});
```

The main thing is not adding the `"g"` because it doesn't do what you want here.  Beyond that, I think your only real error is which version of vee-validate you're using.  If you use the latest (3.2.0), your code mostly works and it certainly passes the value of "@from" not that string.

See here for a working example based off your code:  https://codesandbox.io/s/veevalidate-30-cross-field-validation-9nebh

I removed the "time" validator because your `greater` validator seems to do the same thing already, and I didn't have the code for it anyways.

Comment: I was using vee-validate 3.0.5 and with vee-validate 3.2.0 this problem doesn't exist.   Thnx for pointing on useless regex, especially on g modifier at the end.